# While debugging R code why can't I see local variables in the environment pane?

Tags: r, debugging, environment-variables, rstudio

I created a function foo that is called by my R code. My main program and foo are in different files.

I entered a browser() statement inside foo. When I run the program the code stops at that browser() call (actually a few lines above it).

I keep hitting n and the cursor moves down. A few variables are created and others, like the arguments of foo, already existed. I can see them by typing ls() in the console.

In the environment pane there is a menu where I can choose between environments. The name of my function foo is visible while I am debuggin inside it. It is the top item in the menu. If I click on the menu I can also see Global Environment and the names of some packages.

However, I cannot see the names of the variables in any of these environments when I choose their environments in the menu. The Environment window stays blank.

If am not debugging I can see the Global Environment variables and the package variables in the Environment pane when I choose the corresponding item from the menu.

Is this the way the RStudio environment pane works? That is, it stays blank when one is debugging?

I prepared an example with minimal code. This is the code in the file with the function that is called:

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  z <- 1
  w <- 2
  browser()
  x + y + z + w
}
```

This is the code in the main file:

```
source("C://Dropbox/Code/R/StackOverflow1.R")

x <- 100
y <- 10

foo(x, y)
```

Comment: The environment panel seems to be updating for me. What version of RStudio and R are you running? It might help to include an actual example that we can run just to make sure we are doing the same thing and can talk about specific variables rather than the general case.

Comment: R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15),  RStudio Version 1.4.1106
I added an example, hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I got this from RStudio support and it worked:

"Go to Tools -> Global Options -> Advanced -> Debugging, and uncheck "Use debug error handler only when my code contains errors", then restart."